# Link_to href and text confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have document download functionality for a page. This is the code in place

```
%td= link_to upload.file, '#', class: " bogus btn btn-xs #{'btn-primary' if upload.published}"
```

The problem with this is that results in the following html:

```
<a href="#" class=" bogus btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-original-title="" title="">/public/uploads/file/46/random.txt</a>
```

I thought it would be as simple as changing the structure to this:

```
%td= link_to '#', upload.file, class: " bogus btn btn-xs #{'btn-primary' if upload.published}"
```

which would result in the following html:

```
<a href="/public/uploads/file/46/random.txt" class=" bogus btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-original-title="" title="">#</a>
```

This however results in the following error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for FileUploader:Class
```

Comment: Try `link_to '#', upload.file_url`

Comment: Maybe better this `link_to '#', upload.file.url, class: '...'`

Answer (score 0):

You might what to try something like this `<%= link_to "#", upload.file.url, class: " bogus btn btn-xs #{'btn-primary' if upload.published}" %>`